# Will there be a review counter / indicator feature?

Tags: feature-request

I interested in that will there be a counter / small indicator around the review link for users who are eligible to review posts, to indicate that there are actions to be taken? I mean a small counter to the review link beside our profile link something similar like inbox that shows a number of incoming messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking about a counter which counts the open tasks in review? This exists, you need to reload the page for it. It may contain still open tasks that you have voted on already or cannot vote, so it is not too accurate. See this image from physics.se:

[image]

Comment: Yes I'm already familiar with this :) I am interested in having a small counter at the "status bar" where the review link resides beside our profile link.

Comment: This counter is present in the status bar. See the small 5 in the box?

Comment: hmmm I see it on the picture now - I missed for the first time. But I've never seen it in live, so I have to manually check every time if there's something new. Is this because Biology is 'just' a beta site? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: No, it appears on bio.sx as well. I only took this image because I didn't want to make a screenshot. What tasks can you review now?

Comment: Close/reopen votes , first posts, late answers

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand your last comment. I've already reviewed some of these task I just have to manually check if there's new stuff.

Comment: The review counter only appears for 10k+ users (2k+ on beta sites like this one).

Answer (score 3):

If you use Google Chrome or are willing to use Chrome, you can download and install an add on which will show you when there are review task for everything not just edits. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, you don't get a count but it lights up when a task is available and directly takes you to that task whereas suggested edits only takes to edits and you would still need to click review tasks to see if there are other review tasks.

The add on can be found [here](http://calculus7.org/scripts/). Scroll down until you see Task-Specific Review Indicators and that is what you want.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm kind of anti-Chrome....